# R: Replace NA with other variables in the df using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to replace the NA values in my df using tidyverse, the values I want should be caculated from other cols:

input:

```
ID,    X1,    X2,    X3,
"A",  0.96,   NA,    0.97,
"B",  1.00,   NA,    1.01,
"C",  0.98,   0.03,  NA,
"A",  1.00,   NA,    1.00,
"D",  NA,     0.05,  0.99,
```

My wish is to find in each row which variable of all three `X1, X2, X3` is NA and to calcualte it with the sum of the other two variables

output:

```
ID,    X1,    X2,    X3,
"A",  0.96,   1.93,  0.97,
"B",  1.00,   2.01,  1.01,
"C",  0.98,   0.03,  1.01,
"A",  1.00,   2.00,   1.00,
"D",  1.04,   0.05,  0.99,
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nice question. Thank you!

Here we use:

1. `rowSums` to add a column with the row sums of X1-X3
2. then we `mutate` `across` all `X` and
3. `coalesce` each `X` with `rowSum1`
4. surprisingly `rowSum1` column is gone away because not needed ->
5. this is due to the fantastic `.keep="unused"` argument of `mutate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(rowsum1 = rowSums(select(., starts_with("X")), na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("X"), ~coalesce(.,rowsum1)),.keep="unused")
```

Output:

```
  ID       X1    X2    X3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      0.96  1.93  0.97
2 B      1     2.01  1.01
3 C      0.98  0.03  1.01
4 A      1     2     1   
5 D      1.04  0.05  0.99
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `NA` value with `sum` of other non-NA value in the row.

This can be done using base R `apply` -

```
df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) 
             replace(x, is.na(x), sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))))
df

#  ID   X1   X2   X3
#1  A 0.96 1.93 0.97
#2  B 1.00 2.01 1.01
#3  C 0.98 0.03 1.01
#4  A 1.00 2.00 1.00
#5  D 1.04 0.05 0.99
```

and similarly with `purrr::pmap_df` -

```
df[-1] <- purrr::pmap_df(df[-1], ~{
  x <- c(...)
  replace(x, is.na(x), sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [Ronak Shah's `purrr` version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67849921/7010056), but keeping the ID column is this:

```
library(purrr)

pmap_df(df, \(...) {
  vars <- list(...)
  map(vars, ~ ifelse(is.na(.), do.call(sum, c(vars[-1], na.rm = T)), .))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One more approach using `dplyr::cur_data()`

```
df %>% rowwise() %>%
  mutate(replace(cur_data()[-1], is.na(cur_data()[-1]), sum(cur_data()[-1], na.rm = T)))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  ID       X1    X2    X3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      0.96  1.93  0.97
2 B      1     2.01  1.01
3 C      0.98  0.03  1.01
4 A      1     2     1   
5 D      1.04  0.05  0.99
```

OR without using `rowwise` and using `across` instead

```
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('X'), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), rowSums(cur_data()[-1], na.rm = T), .)))

  ID   X1   X2   X3
1  A 0.96 1.93 0.97
2  B 1.00 2.01 1.01
3  C 0.98 0.03 1.01
4  A 1.00 2.00 1.00
5  D 1.04 0.05 0.99
```